# GETUTCDATE en Indexed View Certificacion MSCA

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos

estoy preparándome para tomar el examen para obtener la certificacion de microsoft de SQL Server, para ello conseguí ejemplos de preguntas que me pueden tomar en el examen, sin embargo hay una de las preguntas la cual no logro entender.

*You have a date related query that would benefit from an indexed view. You need to create the indexed view. Which two Transact-SQL functions can you use? (Each correct answer presents a complete solution. Choose two.)
A.    DATEADD
B.    AT TIME ZONE
C.    GETUTCDATE
D.    DATEDIFF*

Tanto en una aplicación que utilizo para prepararme como buscando por internet, he econtrado que siempre responden que las respuestas correctas son la C y la D haciendo referencia al sitio de microsft https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#DateandTimeFunctions.

Sin embargo no entiendo el porque.

Yo entiendo que pregunta "Cuales funciones T-SQL se pueden usar" se refiere a la creacion de la vista indexada, con lo cual GETUTCDATE es no deterministico y por ende no se puede utilizar en la creación de una vista indexada.

Estoy entendiendo mal la pregunta?

Igualmente al margen que la respuesta ofrecida no la entiendo, tampoco entiendo cuales 2 serían las respuestas, ya que para mi serian A, B y C.

Alguien podrá ayudarme a entender?

Muchas Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Las respuestas correctas serían A y D. Porque son las únicas que usan funciones determinísticas (`DATEADD` y `DATEDIFF`).

`AT TIME ZONE` y `GETUTCDATE` no son determinísticas y no pueden ser utilizadas para vistas indexadas.

Si encuentras que hay otras respuestas disponibles, es probable que estén en un error. Dejo unos ejemplos que puedes validar.

#### Con funciones permitidas

```
USE AdventureWorks2016
GO

CREATE VIEW Sales.vSalesOrder 
WITH SCHEMABINDING  
AS
SELECT SalesOrderID, OrderDate,   
    DATEDIFF( dd, 0, DATEADD( dd, SalesOrderID, OrderDate)) AS DiasDesde1900
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader; 

GO
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX CI_vSalesOrder ON Sales.vSalesOrder(DiasDesde1900);

GO

DROP VIEW Sales.vSalesOrder
```

#### Con funciones NO permitidas

```
USE AdventureWorks2016
GO

CREATE VIEW Sales.vSalesOrder 
WITH SCHEMABINDING  
AS
SELECT SalesOrderID, OrderDate,   
    GETUTCDATE() AS SomeDate
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader; 

GO
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX CI_vSalesOrder ON Sales.vSalesOrder(OrderDate_TimeZonePST);

GO

DROP VIEW Sales.vSalesOrder
```

.

```
USE AdventureWorks2016
GO

CREATE VIEW Sales.vSalesOrder 
WITH SCHEMABINDING  
AS
SELECT SalesOrderID, OrderDate,   
    DATEADD( dd, 1, OrderDate AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time' AS OrderDate_TimeZonePST  
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader; 

GO
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX CI_vSalesOrder ON Sales.vSalesOrder(OrderDate_TimeZonePST);

GO

DROP VIEW Sales.vSalesOrder
```

Comment: Gracias Luis, son las 2 que suponía correctas, aunque At Time Zone también consideraba determinística, a raiz de tu respuesta busqué porque no es deterministica y es por el horario de verano. Muchas Gracias! No estoy tan perdido entonces